# Java heap size is 20x greater then -Xmx - How is that possible?

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, jvm

An Elasticsearch instance is running on a VM with 32 core CPU and 120gb memory.

While I was debugging for a performance issue found this result for `htop`

Mem usage 
[image]

Elastic search Java process consuming 52% of memory ~60gb
[image]

jstat result

```
jstat -gc 11660
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
195904.0 195904.0  0.0   30111.4 1567680.0 1146433.0 59906496.0 1432277.9  73684.0 63888.5  0.0    0.0   2122077 150951.979   6      0.837 150952.816
```

The `-Xms2g` and `-Xmx2g` settings are clearly visible for the java process.

How is this possible ? How can the memory usage go beyond `-Xmx2g` ?

Comment: Figured out. For unknown reasons `-Xmx` has been repeated with 2gb & 69gb

Answer (score 3):

What top and htop don't show is the level of the JVM heap, which is different from the total physical memory consumed by the Java process.

Underneath, Lucene will map the index segment files directly into memory without leveraging the heap. So, in your Java process, Elasticsearch itself might well make use of a 2GB heap, but the underlying Lucene library might consume much more memory depending on how big the segments that need to be loaded into memory are.

Another answer on the same subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232221/4604579

Comment: Just figured out `-Xmx` is actually repeated with 2gb & 59gb where the later is buried inside the long list of java params. So now it makes sense although not sure why it's repeating. Thanks @Val

Comment: anything else needed?

Comment: Not exactly. If you check the comment its a different issue for me.